# Is it possible to make Google Closure compiler *not* inline certain functions?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, js1k

Closure compiler is inlining a function, but the code size is smaller if that function is not inlined (I only care about code size - this is for [JS1k](http://js1k.com/2010-xmas/)). Can I tell the compiler that I don't want that function inlined?

**Edit:** Just to explain a bit better, here's my function:

```
function lineTo(x,y) {
  a.lineTo(x,y);
}
```

where `a` in the canvas context. Because there are so many `a.lineTo`s in the code, having this function used is worth it. Like this, my code is 1019 bytes (and all the `lineTo`s are replaced by `a.lineTo`). If I change the function to:

```
function lineTo(x,y) {
  a.lineTo(x,y);
  console.log();
}
```

the new line somehow forces the compiler to not inline this function, which gives me 993 bytes. So if I could get rid of the `console.log();` I'd save another 14 bytes.

Comment: http://code.google.com/intl/en/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels.html "The compiler only inlines functions when it determines that inlining is safe and saves space." ... maybe the doc is wrong or there is bug in the complier.

Comment: @timdream See my edit - it looks like it will automatically inline a one-line function even if inlining increases the size compared to leaving it.

Answer (score 4):

From [the tutorial](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html):

> If...you find that Closure Compiler is removing functions you want to keep, there are two ways to prevent this:
>   
> * Move your function calls into the code processed by Closure Compiler.
>   
> * Export the symbols you want to keep.

You probably want the second, which is [discussed here](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html#export), but basically comes down to explicitly setting it as a `window` property:

```
function foo() {
}
window['foo'] = foo;
```

For your JS1k submission, you'd just leave the last line off as it's unneeded. note that Closure will still rename the function, but as it starts renaming your symbols with the name `a` and continues from there, it's unlikely to make your names *longer* overall.

You can try it out with the [online compiler service](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home). If you paste this in:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE
function hello(name) {
  alert('Hello, ' + name);
}
hello('New user');
```

...the compiled result is

```
alert("Hello, New user");
```

But if you add

```
window['hello'] = hello;
```

...to the end, the compiled result is:

```
function a(b){alert("Hello, "+b)}a("New user");window.hello=a;
```

Comment: Is "removing" the same thing as "inlining?"

Comment: @Robert: No, they also mean dead code removal. But it also prevents inlining.

Comment: That kind of works. I get to 995 bytes like that, because it generates `window.lineTo=n;` in the output, which is unnecessary.

Comment: @Skilldrick: LOL, I must have been adding the *"For your JS1k submission, you'd just leave the last line off as it's unneeded."* as you were commenting. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Thanks. So are you suggesting just deleting that line from the minified version? I'd prefer not to do that, as I've currently got compilation as an automatic build step. But if that's the only option, then at least it works!

Comment: @Skilldrick: Yeah, the line doesn't do anything and it adds an unnecessary 16 characters to your submission. You could always add a further build step post-processing the compiler result (`sed` would be sufficient, in a *nix environment).

Comment: @T.J. I was just thinking along those lines. Guess I'd better learn `sed`! Thanks for your help.

Comment: `sed -i 's/window\.lineTo=.;//' kave-min.js` did it. Sorted!

Comment: @Skilldrick: There you go. :-)

Comment: T.J. thanks for the answer! But can you answer a related question I posted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929970/is-there-a-way-to-tell-google-closure-compiler-to-not-inline-my-local-function

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but as of [v20180101](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Releases#january-01-2018-v20180101), Google Closure Compiler has an annotation that prevents inlining: [`@noinline`](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#noinline).

In your original example, all you'd need is to add jsdoc with this annotation in front of the function that shouldn't be inlined:

```
/** @noinline */
function hello(name) {
  alert('Hello, ' + name);
}
hello('New user');
```