# Is there a way to tell Google Closure Compiler to *NOT* inline my local functions?

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy, asset-pipeline, google-closure-compiler

**Here's what I'm looking for:**

- **I want to use the wonderful features of SIMPLE mode minification while disabling just one specific feature (disable local function inline).**

- **UPDATE: The answer is NO, it's not possible given my setup.** But for me there is a workaround given I am using Grails.
- As @Chad has explained below, "This violates core assumptions of the compiler". See my UPDATE3 below for more info.

---

IN QUESTION FORM:

- I'm using `CompilationLevel.SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` which does everything I want, except that it's inlining my local functions.
- Is there any way around this? For example, is there a setting I can place in my JS files to tell Google Closure not to inline my local functions?

It would be cool to have some directives at the top of my javascript file such as:

```
// This is a JS comment...
// google.closure.compiler = [inlineLocalFunctions: false]
```

I'm developing a Grails app and using the [Grails asset-pipeline](https://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline) plugin, which uses Google Closure Compiler (hereafter, Compiler). The plugin supports the different minification levels that Compiler supports via the Grails config [grails.assets.minifyOptions](http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/configuration.html). This allows for 'SIMPLE', 'ADVANCED', 'WHITESPACE_ONLY'.

AssetCompiler.groovy (asset-pipeline plugin) calls `ClosureCompilerProcessor.process()`

That eventually assigns `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` on the CompilerOptions object. And by doing so, `CompilerOptions.inlineLocalFunctions = true` as a byproduct (this is hard coded behavior in Compiler). If I were to use `WHITESPACE_ONLY` the result would be `inlineLocalFunctions=false`.

So by using Asset Pipeline's 'SIMPLE' setting, local functions are being inlined and that is causing me trouble. Example: ExtJS [ext-all-debug.js](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/extjs/blob/4.2.1.883/ext-all-debug.js) which uses lots of local functions.

SO post [Is it possible to make Google Closure compiler *not* inline certain functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297685/is-it-possible-to-make-google-closure-compiler-not-inline-certain-functions) provides some help. I can use its `window['dontBlowMeAway'] = dontBlowMeAway` trick to keep my functions from inlining. However I have LOTS of functions and I'm not about to manually do this for each one; nor would I want to write a script to do it for me. Creating a JS model and trying to identity local functions doesn't sound safe, fun nor fast.

The previous SO post directs the reader to https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#removal, where the `window['bla']` trick is explained, and it works.

Wow thanks for reading this long.

Help? :-)

---

**UPDATE1:**

Okay. While spending all the effort in writing this question, I may have a trick that could work. Grails uses Groovy. Groovy makes method call interception easy using its MetaClass API.

I'm going to try intercepting the call to:

```
com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.compile(
    List<T1> externs, List<T2> inputs, CompilerOptions options)
```

My intercepting method will look like:

```
options.inlineLocalFunctions=false
// Then delegate call to the real compile() method
```

It's bed time so I'll have to try this later. Even so, it would be nice to solve this without a hack.

---

**UPDATE2:**
The response in a similar post ([Is it possible to make Google Closure compiler *not* inline certain functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297685/is-it-possible-to-make-google-closure-compiler-not-inline-certain-functions)) doesn't resolve my problem because of the large quantity of functions I need inlined. I've already explained this point.

Take the ExtJS file I cited above as an example of why the above [similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297685/is-it-possible-to-make-google-closure-compiler-not-inline-certain-functions) doesn't resolve my problem. Look at the raw code for [ext-all-debug.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bjornharrtell/extjs/4.2.1.883/ext-all-debug.js). Find the byAttribute() function. Then keep looking for the string "byAttribute" and you'll see that it is part of strings that are being defined. I am not familiar with this code, but I'm supposing that these string-based values of `byAttribute` are later being passed to [JS's eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function for execution. Compiler does not alter these values of `byAttribute` when it's part of a string. Once `function byAttribute` is inlined, attempts to call the function is no longer possible.

---

**UPDATE3:** I attempted two strategies to resolve this problem and both proved unsuccessful. However, I successfully implemented a workaround. My failed attempts:

1. Use Groovy method interception (Meta Object Protocol, aka MOP) to intercept `com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.compile()`.
2. Fork the closure-compiler.jar (make my own custom copy) and modify `com.google.javascript.jscomp.applySafeCompilationOptions()` by setting `options.setInlineFunctions(Reach.NONE);` instead of LOCAL.

Method interception doesn't work because `Compiler.compile()` is a Java class which is invoked by a Groovy class marked as `@CompileStatic`. That means Groovy's MOP is not used when `process()` calls Google's `Compiler.compile()`. Even `ClosureCompilerProcessor.translateMinifyOptions()` (Groovy code) can't be intercepted because the class is `@CompileStatic`. The only method that can be intercepted is `ClosureCompilerProcessor.process()`.

Forking Google's closure-compiler.jar was my last ugly resort. But just like @Chad said below, simply inserting `options.setInlineFunctions(Reach.NONE)` in the right place didn't resurrect my inline JS functions names. I tried toggling other options such as `setRemoveDeadCode=false` to no avail. I realized what Chad said was right. I would end up flipping settings around and probably destroying how the minification works.

**My solution:** I pre-compressed ext-all-debug.js with UglifyJS and added them to my project. I could have named the files `ext-all-debug.min.js` to do it more cleanly but I didn't. Below are the settings I placed in my Grails Config.groovy:

```
grails.assets.minifyOptions = [
    optimizationLevel: 'SIMPLE' // WHITESPACE_ONLY, SIMPLE or ADVANCED
]

grails.assets.minifyOptions.excludes = [
    '**ext-all-debug.js',
    '**ext-theme-neptune.js'
]
```

Done. Problem solved.

Keywords: minify, minification, uglify, UglifyJS, UglifyJS2

Comment: Can you explain **why** the local function inlining causes you problems? There are multiple techniques to prevent this, but I need to know the core reasons to suggest one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make Google Closure compiler \*not\* inline certain functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297685/is-it-possible-to-make-google-closure-compiler-not-inline-certain-functions)

Comment: Thanks @ChadKillingsworth. I've added "UPDATE2" to my question as a response to your question. Indeed I have taken you comment about "possible duplicate" into consideration if you read my original question, which you probably did anyway. Peace bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you would either need to make a custom build of the compiler or use the Java API.

However - disabling inlining is not enough to make this safe. Renaming and dead code elimination will also cause problems. This violates core assumptions of the compiler. This local function is ONLY referenced from within strings.

This code is only safe for the `WHITESPACE_ONLY` mode of the compiler.

Comment: You were right. See UPDATE3 for details and my successful workaround. Thanks Chad =)

Answer (score 0):

Use the function constructor

```
var fnc = new Function("param1", "param2", "alert(param1+param2);");
```

Closure will leave the String literals alone.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function